# how to find out existance of specific pattern in a list of integers by help of Linq. C#

Tags: c#, linq

How to determine a range in a list of integer follow specific pattern.
For example, we have a list like this:

```
List<int> ints = new List<int>(){4,5,2,6,8,4,5,6,5,6,8,9,9};
```

`Exists` and `Any` could check if an element satisfies specific condition.

But what if I want to know if there is any three items in row that incremental values(plus 1): here they are `{4, 5, 6}`.

Comment: Why is LINQ a requirement?

Comment: You could try to mix Regex with LINQ but it's not a great idea, @Patrick answer is more elegant easy way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Patrick already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33518157/142637) your question with a good solution, but if you're really looking for a LINQ-only way, you could use `Aggregate`:

```
var inputs = new List<IEnumerable<int>>
{
    new List<int>{ 4,5,2,6,8,4,5,6,5,6,8,9,9 },
    new List<int>{ 1,2,3 },
    new List<int>{ 1,2,4 },
};

foreach(var input in inputs)
{
    var result = input.Aggregate(Enumerable.Empty<int>(), 
                    (agg, cur) => agg.Count() == 3 ? agg
                                    : agg.Any() && cur == agg.Last() + 1
                                        ? agg.Concat(new []{cur})
                                        : new []{cur});

    Console.WriteLine(result.Count() >= 3 ? String.Join(", ", result) : "not found");
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) I guess it is the best I can get by linq.

Answer (score 1):

I would drop the LINQ requirement. It is very hard, maybe even impossible. A regular `foreach` statement is better suited for this:

```
List<int> sequence = new List<int>();
List<int> longestSequence = null;
int previous = 0;
foreach (int i in ints)
{
    if (i != previous + 1 && sequence.Count > 0)
    {
        if (longestSequence == null || longestSequence.Count < sequence.Count)
        {
            longestSequence = sequence;
        }

        sequence = new List<int>();
    }

    sequence.Add(i);
    previous = i;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Patric, your solution is clear and neat. However, I am just looking for linq solution. If it is not really possible I will accept your answer after a while.

Comment: Great, but you should learn each technology within its scope, this behavior is beyond LINQ scope ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to take all of the groups of 3 and then see which group(s) meet your n, n+1 and n+2 rule

```
var results = Enumerable.Range(0, ints.Count - 3)
            .Select(n => ints.Skip(n).Take(3).ToArray())
            .Where(three => three[0]+1 == three[1] && three[0]+2 == three[2])
            .ToArray();
```